# Elementary set theory equivalent statements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B\subset M$. Prove the following statement:

$A\subset B \iff A^c\cup B = M$

M is universal set and $A^c$ is complement of A.

I can kind a solve this using bunch of reasoning but in no real way using set laws or using arbitrary elements to prove that $A^c\cup B \subset M$ and $M\subset A^c\cup B$. I'm pretty sure its very trivial but I'm just looking for a very formal way to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide it into 2 proofs, one assuming that $A\subset B$ is true and the other assuming that $A^c\cup B=M$ is true

---

($\Rightarrow$)

We know that $A\cup A^c=M$ right? We also know that
$$\forall x \in A: x\in B\\\forall y\notin B: y\notin A\implies y\in A^c$$we know that because $A\subset B$

Now from what we said that at the start we can have $\forall z\in M, \exists x\in A,\exists y\in A^c$ such that $z=y$ **or** $z=x$. Now from the second line we can say $\forall z\in M, \exists x\in B,\exists y\in A^c$ such that $z=y$ **or** $z=x$ instead, thus $A^c\cup B=M$

---

Now the other way around:

($\Leftarrow$)

Let's assume that we have $x\in A$ that is not in $B$, but if $x\in A$ then it can not be in $A^c$ so $x\notin A^c\cup B$. But we defined $A$ to be subset of $M$ so $x\in M$, this is contradiction hence $A\subset B$

---

Combine those 2 and we done